# how to build falcon with cython using pipenv

Tags: falconframework, pipenv

In the [falcon docs](http://falcon.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/install.html) it is mentioned that in order to build falcon with cython the following commands need to be issued:

> $ pip install cython
>
> $ pip install --no-binary :all: falcon

The question is how to do this with pipenv.

First of all i want to say Pipfile that i have build dependency cython.

I want also to pass the parameters --no-binary :all: falcon to pip.